# FTP file upload feature on Wordpress page

Tags: node.js, wordpress, web

I have this Wordpress page that a colleague of mine has been working on. The user has to be able to login in and upload some files. We are thinking about using this plugin for logging in

https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/

When logged in, the user has access to a page with a feature where he/she can select a file from his/her harddisk. The selected file should then be uploaded to an FTP server. When the upload is complete, the page should display a list of the files the user has already uploaded and have an option to delete each individual file.

I realise that this requires sending commands to the the FTP server (LIST, DELE, MKD etc).

I have considered making my on Node.js server and letting the server handle the FTP upload, but I am also thinking that there should be a Wordpress plugin for this. I have tried searching, but all I can find is instructions on how to use Wordpress' own FTP upload function to deploy a site, which is not particularly helpfull for me. Also, I don't have any experience with Wordpress, but have some web experience, so making sense of it shouldn't be difficult.

So have any of you guys done some similar before and maybe know a plugin? Or made your own server application for something like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mains problems about upload by users in wp-upload is security, and the files type accepted by the wp uploader. It's better to use our own code, that sanitize the file following your parameters.

You can try:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/
or
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/

Answer (score 1):

Well this is fairly simple if you have some php skills. You dont even need any kind of ftp access. So here is a basic breakdown of how it should be done the **"wordpress way"**.

**1) Separate dashboard/user areas for different users (the page they see
    after login)**

Well its not a good idea to give users access to the backend/admin area and is not very user friendly as well, so you can look into theme-my-login plugin which does a great job of creating login pages and separate pages where users are redirected after login.

**2) Then you need to have a upload area where users can upload the movies from their computer**

For this you can look us wordpress attachment functions. You have functions for uploading, deleting etc. Just create a simple form and grab the uploaded file and pass them through these functions (you should look into sanitizing data properly / validation), you might also need to increase the size of uploaded files through php.ini etc.

wp_insert_attachment, wp_delete_attachment, wp_get_attachment_url

**3) A repository of all movies uploaded by specific user**

This is a piece of cake with user meta's. The above described attachment functions comes with action hooks, Hooks are like triggers that gets triggered when someone does some action. So once the attachment is uploaded, you can hook into that action and grab the id of the uploaded attachment, name of uploaded attachment etc and them save them to the logged in user's meta. Its better if you use an array of values and then encode them into json. This way a list of all user movies can be store in a single database entry, which would be very efficient.

For creating and updating user meta's you should this function update_user_meta, delete_user_meta, etc.

Now to show all movies by a user, you can use something like **get_user_meta('movie_list')**

Comment: I don't have any php experience at all :( But thanks for your answer.